# 1С программирование (Конфигурация)

Tags: 1с

Здравствуйте! Как в 1С предприятие конфигурации создать начисление заработной платы? С чего начать ? Нужно ли с начало создать документ Начисления? Спасибо.

Comment: Посмотреть как это реализовано в ЗУПе, для примера и понимания вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Начисление ЗП, Расчет ЗП, Расчетные ведомости, Ведомость в банк/кассу
(А вообще надо указывать о какой именно конфигурации идет речь)